# VirtualBox or else programs to run Mac OS virtually on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine

VirtualBox or other programs to run Mac OS virtually on Windows 7?

any idea will help me to enlarge the boundaries surround me nowadays.

Comment: That is against the OS X license. You aren't allowed to do that.

Comment: @Sebastian so it is possible but according to license I can not do that. I see now...

Comment: If something is written on the license, doesn't mean it is valid. Unless you are a lawyer, as far as you know that could be an illegal clause, hence just ignorable. Just answer the questions please. Unless you *are* a lawyer, of course.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox 3.2 supports Mac out of the box.
http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=2076

Answer (score 1):

This link shows a good rundown of what is needed:

> http://www.sysprobs.com/install-mac-os-1055-leopard-virtualbox-314-installation-dvd

[image]

> Everybody likes work with Mac OS X without buying Mac Hardware on your normal PC, If you are a person like this, then you reached correct place. This article explains how to install Mac OS X 10.5.5 Leopard on VirtualBox 3.1.4.  No any additional hardware or software needs to be purchased for this installation. This method is completely for testing purpose and not to use permanently or in production environment